# Index inside an index , neo4j

Tags: indexing, neo4j, nested-lists

Assume I have the following data:

I have an **index - meal**
Inside the index **meal**, I want another index named **pizza**, and following **ingredients**:

The relationship is : meal->pizza->ingredients

For example,

```
(meal index)
HAWAIIAN pizza(pizza) using sugar,oil,pineapple,others(ingredients)
  Indian pizza(pizza) using curry powder,butter,others(ingredients)
```

1. How do I set the **nested list** in neo4j?
2. How do I set the key,value pair?

Comment: the lucene index is full text - thus querying any part of the indexed string will match.

Comment: @Huei could you please make an example graph at console.neo4j.org and state the desired queries? Har dot guess form the info above.

Comment: that means, you can't do any kind of "sub-index" inside the index, but you can still have just one index for all keywords, than querying the node with `start n=node:meals('name:pizza')` and puting a property on the node `n.type='meal'` or for ingredients `start n=node:meals('name:butter') where n.type='ingredient' return n;`

Comment: means adding one new property to pretend sub-index? ok, i got it!